# How can I select only the basic Ethernet interface ipo Virtual Ethernet or other interfaces in a batch with WMIC NICCONFIG?

Tags: batch, ethernet, network-interface, wmic

I have a small subroutine giving the description and index of the network interface called 'CARTE', so when called with %CARTE%=wireless, it returns the correct index of wireless interface (2), but when called with %CARTE%=Ethernet, it returns the index (12) of the Virtualbox Virtual Ethernet interface instead of the Ethernet motherboard (1).

Command line displays :

```
wmic nicconfig get description,index /format:csv

Node,Description,Index
P50-CLAUDE,Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter,0
P50-CLAUDE,Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM,1
P50-CLAUDE,Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260,2
P50-CLAUDE,Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter,3
P50-CLAUDE,Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter,4
P50-CLAUDE,WAN Miniport (SSTP),5
P50-CLAUDE,WAN Miniport (IKEv2),6
P50-CLAUDE,WAN Miniport (L2TP),7
P50-CLAUDE,WAN Miniport (PPTP),8
P50-CLAUDE,WAN Miniport (PPPOE),9
P50-CLAUDE,WAN Miniport (IP),10
P50-CLAUDE,WAN Miniport (IPv6),11
P50-CLAUDE,WAN Miniport (Network Monitor),12
P50-CLAUDE,Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network),13
P50-CLAUDE,Windscribe VPN,14
P50-CLAUDE,VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,15
P50-CLAUDE,RAS Async Adapter,16
P50-CLAUDE,Windscribe Windtun420,17
```

How can I restrict search of index to a value of 3 ? I have tried something like "&& where %idx% LWR" or "&& where %idx% < '3'" but without success...
Can somebody help and explain my errors please ?
Thank you !

PS : I know batch and WMIC are deprecated, but this is just for a small and quick hardware testing...

```
:GETNIC
rem -------------------------------------------
rem returns DESCRIP and IDX of interface CARTE
set nicline="wmic nicconfig where "description like '%%%CARTE%%%'" get description^,index^ /format:csv^"
for /F "tokens=2-3 delims=," %%a in ('%nicline%') Do (
    set "DESCR=%%~a" & set "IDX=%%~b"
)
exit /b %DESCR%, %IDX%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How can I restrict search of index to a value of 3?*
>
> - I'm not sure that I understand 100% of your question,
>   but where I understand it, I suggest you limit the output of the index:
>
> - ```
>   index<=3  
>   index>=1 and index<=3
>   ```
>
> - Or use `| findstr /End` by "`,`" + `[Rex-Range]`
>
>   ```
>   for /F ... ('%nicline% ^| findstr /e ^,[0-3]')do ... 
>   for /f tokens^=2*^delims^=^, %i in ('wmic nicconfig get  description^,index /format:csv ^| findstr /e ^,[0-3]
>         ')do echo/ %%i,%%j
>   ```

```
wmic nicconfig where "index<=3" get description /format:csv
wmic nicconfig where "index>=1 and index<=3" get description,index /format:csv
```